# Collapse jquery panel after 5 seconds, or allow manual close on click

Tags: jquery, delay, slide

I am trying to have a panel slide open and close on click of a link, but I also want the panel to collapse after 5 seconds if the user hasn't done anything. I have this sort of working with .delay, but during that 5 seconds, I can't toggle the panel close with the .seriesLink because I don't know how to intercept the delay. So basically the panel is stuck open for 5 seconds right now even if the user tries to close it by clicking the Series link again. 
Here is my HTML and jQuery:

```
var container = $('.menu');
    $('.seriesLink').click(function( event ){
        // Prevent the default event
        event.preventDefault(); 
        // Toggle the slide based on its current visibility.
        if (container.is( ":visible" )){
            // Hide - slide up
            container.slideUp( );
        } 
        if (container.is(':hidden')) {
            // Show - slide down, pause 5 seconds, slide up
            container.slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp(); 
        }
    });
```

```html
<a href="#" class="seriesLink">Series</a>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="subMenu">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Link title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Link title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Link title</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay function will stop all javascript in the current context from running.
You need to use setTimeout to schedule a future event.

I implemented a version in this jsfiddle that will cancel any previous events if the link is clicked more than once:

http://jsfiddle.net/FtqG8/

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to add the clearTimeout just as you posted it!

Answer (score 3):

Use `setTimeout`:

```
container.slideDown();
setTimeout(function () {
    if (container.is(":visible")) {
        container.slideUp();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.seriesLink').click(function( event ){
    // Prevent the default event
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // Toggle the slide based on its current visibility.
    if (container.is( ":visible" )){
        // Hide - slide up
        container.slideUp( );
    } 
    if (container.is(':hidden')) {
        // Show - slide down, pause 5 seconds, slide up
        container.slideDown(function(){
            var self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.slideUp(); 
            },5000);
        });
    }
});
```

doing it like this would preserve the behavior you originally wanted: waiting 5 seconds after the `.slideDown` animation completes, before sliding up.

Comment: This worked perfectly, except I needed clearTimeout also to cancel previous events if the user clicks the link more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your click function:

```
if (container.is(':hidden')) {
    // Show - slide down, pause 5 seconds, slide up
    container.slideDown();
    setTimeout(function(){
        container.slideUp();     
    },5000);
}
```